# What is the way to define an object with a dynamic number of properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to assign the correct shape to an object that serves as the initialValue of the reduce method. This object can have a dynamic number of properties and the name of the key can be the numbers from 1 to 6, the latter defined in the DiceNumber type

```
type DiceNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;

const dataset: DiceNumber[] = [];

function rollDice(): DiceNumber {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1) as DiceNumber;
}

function stats(data: DiceNumber[]) {
  return data.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;

    return a;
  }, {} as any);
}

dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());
dataset.push(rollDice());

console.log(stats(dataset));
```

By not using any I get the following message

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'DiceNumber' can't be used to index type '{}'.   Property '1' does not
> exist on type '{}'

When trying to define an interface in the following way

```
interface MyType {
  [key: DiceNumber]: number;
}
```

I get the following message

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider
> using a mapped object type instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you're looking for is indeed a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  I'd suggest:

```
{ [K in DiceNumber]?: number }
```

which means for each key `K` in `DiceNumber`, the object type has an *optional* property of type `number`.  You can also use built in [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) and call it `Partial<Record<DiceNumber, number>>`.

So your function is now:

```
function stats(data: DiceNumber[]) {
    return data.reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;

        return a;
    }, {} as { [K in DiceNumber]?: number });
}
```

And you can verify that `stats()`'s call signature is

```
/* function stats(data: DiceNumber[]): {
    1?: number | undefined;
    2?: number | undefined;
    3?: number | undefined;
    4?: number | undefined;
    5?: number | undefined;
    6?: number | undefined;
} */
```

as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgYwgOQK4FsBGEBOUC8UAjFAD5QBMZUAzNQCzUCs1AbANwCwAUDwgPYA7AM7AoAEwCGwScIjAAXLEQoM2HAG0AugSjauvbgDNUghMDhCoOfgBtb8JAAoAlEseqsuKAG8eUAOt5VBxBKABZaQALADojW35+HCdI4FicSUFxfnRXKAAqKFYoAGpiFyhZZSQ0LxwDAF8eHhMzCytRaWEnKRl3FVr1bQq-bkCg4BCw3skYnAhxVGcnSQAaKAQK-AA+X39xwMkNBB1CFeOdUnIABgqyogN9g4mpyoNxhvWfBsrhXz0ANJQOBhDyDXBaAD8SkEam8DRcjWa3AA9IVWuZLGFOsBujN+jU4ZotG49mNAkRoVBYXVqKZxBAjCCFu9AhQqTT1HSsozmeJWQEaByidyGUzBCynlB6MLaeR6byJfypUxZVz5TzxZLyQFWGrvBqxXzGgUUciZnJgDEwKhhFEnDZ7B5XIieBb5NbbfbHQ4VC6DO6rTa7Q67L7nC5XdxA56Qz7nZGA9JZB7g96wwmozG06GnX7E27k5bY+m8xGs0XU17c+GIP7CzJizn4-mK42q3GM62k+2g9WW+XHtwBCI7BAYgkAOZOHF4yvARNAA)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
type Accumulator = {
    [K in DiceNumber]?: number
}

function stats(data: DiceNumber[]) {
  return data.reduce((a: Accumulator, c: DiceNumber) => {
    a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
}
```